# How to follow a path of urls with Scrapy (online reviews)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, webshop

For my side-job **I am building a webscraper for a consultancy company so they can help clients with their forecasting based on the data scraped from online retailers.** The most important data are of course the reviews, but also price, features, substitutes etc are part of the data scraped.
I am completely new to Scrapy and programming, but have managed so far to create a code that seems to work, partially.
Since the Scrapy project didn't work for me, I used the Scrapinghub tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPvPiMbPSTE&list=PLZyvi_9gamL-EE3zQJbU5N3nzJcfNeFHU&index=2).

The first part works fine: Scrapy follows the individual product urls and scraped the information on there. However, **a part of the reviews is hidden and requires an AJAX call to show them.** Since I am not experienced enough to work with AJAX in Scrapy and don't have the time because it is my last week, I decided to try to follow the url to the page where all the reviews are visible.
This url is scraped from the webpage and looks like this: "/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MultiChannelReviewListAjax?storeId=10259&langId=-11&catEntryId=3744085&mode=tail"

Until now, following this link works in a separate code, but not in the code below. It could be an error in my indentation or the fact that it still uses AJAX in the link, but I have tried a lot and cannot seem to find the solution.
**Does anyone know the best way how I could to this, or improve the separate code as it gives me the "DEBUG crawled (200)" error for some pages while working fine for other?**

Thanks a lot!

```
import scrapy
from time import gmtime, strftime


class MediamarktSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "MediaMarkt_NL"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mediamarkt.nl"]
    download_delay = 2
    cookies_enabled = False
    user_agent = "Googlebot/2.1"
    start_urls = ['http://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/category/_koptelefoons-450727.html']

    # scrape individual product page
    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//*[@class='product-wrapper']//h2/a/@href").extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

        # follow pagination link
        next_page_url =  response.xpath("//*[@class='pagination-next']//a/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        # make sure something is returned    
        def casenull(xpathstring, pos=0):
            try:
                return xpathstring[pos]
            except IndexError:
                return 'none'        

        yield { 
        'Name': response.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="name"]//text()').extract(),
        'Time': strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        'Price': response.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="price"]/@content').extract(),
        'Currency': response.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="priceCurrency"]/@content').extract(),
        'Total_Ratings': casenull(response.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="reviewCount"]/@content').extract()),
        'Average_Rating': casenull(response.xpath('.//*[@class="text-above"]//text()').extract(), 0),
        'Five_Star_Ratings': casenull(response.xpath('.//*[@class="rc-votes"]//text()').extract(), 1),
        'Four_Star_Rating': casenull(response.xpath('.//*[@class="rc-votes"]//text()').extract(), 2),  
        'Three_Star_Rating': casenull(response.xpath('.//*[@class="rc-votes"]//text()').extract(), 3),
        'Two': casenull(response.xpath('.//*[@class="rc-votes"]//text()').extract(), 4),
        'One_Star_Rating': casenull(response.xpath('.//*[@class="rc-votes"]//text()').extract(), 5),
        'Recommendation': casenull(response.xpath('.//*[@class="recommendation"]//text()').extract()),
        'Features': casenull(list(zip(response.xpath('//*[@class="specification"]/dt/text()').extract(), response.xpath('//*[@class="specification"]/dd/text()').extract()))),
        'Pros': casenull([item.strip('\r\t\n') for item in response.xpath('//*[@class="review-features review-pros"]/text()[2]').extract()]),
        'Cons': casenull([item.strip('\r\t\n') for item in response.xpath('//*[@class="review-features review-cons"]/text()[2]').extract()]),
        'Alternatives': casenull(response.xpath('.//*[@class="prodrel-desc"]/h3/a//text()').extract()),
        'Review_Title': casenull([item.strip('\r\t\n') for item in response.xpath('.//li/article/h3//text()').extract()]),
        'Review_Text': casenull([item.strip('\r\t\n') for item in response.xpath('//*[@class="reviews-content js-product-reviews-first"]//article//p[2]//text()').extract()]),
        }

    # follow review url
    for url in urls:
        review_url = response.xpath('.//*[@class="reviews-content reviews-content-remaining js-product-reviews-remaining state-hidden"]//@data-href').extract_first()
        if review_url:
            review_url = response.urljoin(review_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=review_url, callback=self.parse)    

    def parse_details(self, response):
        yield {
        'Review_Titel': [item.strip() for item in response.xpath('//h3//text()').extract()]
        }
```

Comment: You have 2 `parse_details` methods

Comment: Thank you, surfer190! I changed the second one to parse_reviews, but now I get this error: 

"yield scrapy.Request(url=review_url, callback=self.parse_reviews)
               ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function"

Is this an indentation mistake? Sorry the indentation still gets to me some times haha..

Comment: Yeah most likely, try and neaten it up